# Размеры мобильного экрана для адаптивного приложения

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка, табличная-верстка

Для задания на https://www.figma.com/file/5rXv5Q5Jw4auNDZMEsxvD3/%D0%A2%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%92%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B0?node-id=0%3A1 под какие размеры нужно писать адаптив?

Comment: На сегодняшний день мобильный экран - это менее 480 логических пикселей по ширине. Нижняя граница - 360 пикселей. Девайсы с viewport-ом менее 360 пикселей - это редкостные динозавры.

Answer (score 0):

На данный момент минимальной шириной для телефонов является **320px** (меньше не видел), он в *Iphone 5/SE*. Средним значением является **400px**, а для телефонов с большим экраном - **640px** (выше не видел). Все что выше думаю является уже планшетом, нежели чем телефоном.
Откройте *Google Dev. Tool*, далее выберите *Toggle Device Toolbar*, выберите *Iphone 5/SE* для *минимального*, *Iphone 6/7/8 plus* для среднего значения при адаптации.